# Initialize array of objects(which has an array) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, instantiation

I am relatively new to java, and this is only the second time I have ever tried to design a program that has an array of class objects. I am having trouble because when I go into debug mode, it is showing me that the arrays are being built correctly. However, when I try to build a string or even print to the console, I am getting a null pointer exception.

I am trying to make an array of Slot class objects.

```
public class C {
int slotNum;
Slot[] s;


public C(int byteSize, int slotNum){
    this.slotNum = slotNum;

    Slot[] s = new Slot[slotNum]; //create an array of slots

    for(int i = 0; i < slotNum; i++){ //for every slot and instantiate
        s[i] = new Slot(byteSize); 
    }
    display();
}
```

And the Slot class has its own array, block[], constructed by a value passed in through its constructor.

```
public class Slot {

boolean v;
short block[];

public Slot(int byteSize){
    valid = false;

    //Instantiate each element in block[] to 0
    short block[] = new short[byteSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
        block[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Later in the program I then try to print to the console or build a string and it always breaks when I try to use any element in the slot[] in the C class.

Have I instantiated and initialized my 2 different arrays correctly?

Comment: No you are just initializing the local arrays that you make in the constuctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class C {
int slotNum;
Slot[] s;


public C(int byteSize, int slotNum){
this.slotNum = slotNum;

s = new Slot[slotNum]; //create an array of slots

for(int i = 0; i < slotNum; i++){ //for every slot and instantiate
    s[i] = new Slot(byteSize); 
}
display();
}
```

Try something like these instead

```
public class Slot {

boolean v;
short block[];

public Slot(int byteSize){
valid = false;

//Instantiate each element in block[] to 0
block = new short[byteSize];
for(int i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
    block[i] = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: It worked... I can't believe something so simple tripped me up for so long. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
short block[] = new short[byteSize];
```

with

```
block = new short[byteSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use a **`this`** operator to initialize in a constructor so that you may differentiate clearly between local variables and instance variables

```
public Slot(int byteSize){
    valid = false;

    //Instantiate each element in block[] to 0
    this.block = new short[byteSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
        block[i] = 0;
    }
}
```